How to use SearchResultCollection.Contains() function?
I'm trying to figure out how I can use SearchResultCollection.Contains() to search for an existing property inside a SearchResult object without having to loop through the entire collection.
Is this possible?
Here's an example basic code I have:
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry de = new("LDAP://ads.company.com");
DirectorySearcher ds = new(de, "(objectClass=*)")
SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

// How do I use this?  How do I pass a SearchResult object in?
src.Contains(SearchResult result);

Normally I would loop through the collection, but this can be time consuming for large results:
foreach (SearchResult sr in src) {
    if (sr.Properties.Contains("dnsrecord")) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

